# Schedule with Constraints

Tags: c#, algorithm, constraints, artificial-intelligence, scheduling

I want to schedule tasks with Constraints (similar to the job shop scheduling problem) and thought I could use something like the Microsoft Solver Foundation (I need to use C#). But as far as I know you can only solve problems by finding the optimal maximal or minimal which takes way to long. I need an approximation so the scheduling is not optimal (as good as possible) concerning the total time but all the Constraints are fulfilled.
Any ideas how to approach this problem?

Comment: Please present your ideas first.

Comment: Please include a formal definition of the optimization problem mentioned.

Comment: as i mentioned my problem is similar to a job shop scheduling problem - i have i have jobs that needs to be scheduled on machines in a minimal time. The Constraints are e.g. the order of the jobs, the resources, capacity of a machine or a deadline for a specific job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you using [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) solver. It provides you C# API. Basically, it is a [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories) solver, which searches for 'good enough' solution with respect to given constraints. It could be rather difficult to define your problem in [SMTLIB](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-draft-2017-06-05.pdf) language.

If it's too hard for you, look at [Minizinc](http://www.minizinc.org/) or [Clingo](http://potassco.sourceforge.net/) solvers - just generate problem formulation as a text file, run a solver as a separate process from your C# code, parse solution back from output text file.

EDIT

If you want to minimize a length of a schedule, you can try the following approach. Let's assume that **there is** a schedule of length *K*. Is your planning problem satisfiable under this assumption? Let's call a solver to find this out! Generate several problems with different K's and run the solver iteratively. Use *binary search* to reduce the number of trials.